# Lemma 7.8, Applied Analysis (Hunter)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Here's an image of the lemma and the relevant definition preceding it:
[image]

I'm trying to understand the approach to the proof. It's not clear to me why it's sufficient to prove that
$$
||S_M - S_N||_\infty \leq \frac{C_k}{N^{k - 1/2}} \left\vert\left\vert f^{(k)} \right\vert\right\vert.
$$
The way I understand it so far is that if this can be done, then this shows that $S_N$ is Cauchy in $C(\mathbb{T}),$ so it converges to a limit there in the uniform norm. Since $S_N$ is the $N$-th partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$, $S_N \to f$ in the $L^2$-norm. Since $S_N$ converges in the uniform norm, and $S_N \to f$ in the $L^2$-norm, then $S_N \to f$ in the uniform norm. This logic makes sense in the sort of naive "you can't converge to two different limits" intuition, but is that what is actually going on? If this is the case, how can I see this more precisely? And if not, what is this all about?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indeed is an "you can't converge to two different limits"-like argument but you have to be a little careful here. First of all by showing this inequality, as you said, it is proved that $(S_N)$ is Cauchy in $C(\mathbb{T})$. Thus, by completeness there exist a $\tilde{f}\in C(\mathbb{T})$ such that $S_N \to \tilde{f}$ with respect to the supremum norm. In particular $S_N \to \tilde{f}$ with respect to the $L^2(\mathbb{T})$-norm. But as we know the $L^2(\mathbb{T})$-limit of $(S_N)$ is $f$. Therefore $f=\tilde{f}$ a.e.. Then if you consider the essential supremum norm, which in many case has the same notation as the supremum norm, then $\| S_N -f \|_{\infty} = \| S_N - \tilde{f} \|_{\infty}$

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something like this was just missing the details. Much appreciated!